# to-many without insertNewObjectForEntityForName

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject

I have two NSManagedObjects. Both are based off of a selection inside a UITableView.

NSManagedObjects *One = [rootViewController.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:currentSelection];
NSManagedObjects *Two = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

I want to link the two together (to-many), but since the entries already exist, I do not want to use insertNewObjectForEntityForName. If I use insertNewObjectForEntityForName my code works but it links the new entry to an existing entry. I need to link two already existing entries together.

Is this possible and if so, how would you go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. One must use the same NSManagedObjectContext for both NSManagedObjects. Once I had done so, code worked as expected.